# gVim won't open Skeleton Code when creating new file

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am currently using gVim to code in C++. I recently made a skeleton file that includes imports, macros, etc so that every time I make a new .cpp file it automatically adds the skeleton to it.

To do this, I  used this line: **autocmd BufNewFile *.cpp 0r C:/Me/template.cpp**

Whenever I make a new file with command prompt (vim A.cpp), a new file is created in command prompt and the file contains the code skeleton.
However, when using the gVim text editor, when I create a new cpp file it doesn't open with the code skeleton. In order to get the code skeleton on the file, I have to :q out of gVim then :e into the file. After :e'ing into the file, if I make changes and then :wq it says "Can't write viminfo file C:/_viminfo.tmp". Also, when I try to open the file I made with gVim through File Explorer (after getting the template on it), it appears as blank file. How do I get gVim to automatically have the code skeleton whenever I create a new cpp file in gVim?

Comment: What OS are you using?  Are these the same version of Vim?  If not, where did each version of Vim come from and what does `:echo $MYVIMRC` print in each?

Comment: I am on Windows. I am new to Vim. Do I need to put this command (:echo $MYVIMRC) in gVim or in CLI?

Comment: Few strange things for me. What asterisk means at start of your autocmd? Why viminfo is created at the root of C: disk instead of default = windows user directory? Probably vim does not have rights to edit files there or configuration wrong? Check the `$HOME` variable. What its value? Does not matter GUI or CLI if you dont use special config for gvim.